# Passing information from custom SAML JIT handler to error URL

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, saml, jit-handler

Using SSO in SF, there is an option to insert Apex in the `SAML JIT Handler`.
For each scenario, failure or success, there are fields intended for redirecting the user automatically (`Custom Logout URL, Custom Error UR`L) - in our case, the redirect is to different sites.

The error URL working only if an exception thrown in the apex class
The success URL working only if no exception throwed.

When the user (based on his email) is found in the Apex handler, we don't need to pass any parameters, because we have the user.

But when the user isn't found in the Apex handler, an exception is thrown, and the `Custom Error URL` is activated, but we don't know the email he tried to connect with.

Is there a way to transfer parameters into those sites, from the `SAML JIT Handler`?

Many thanks!

[image]